# How to appear selected Item to another page?

Tags: jquery

```
<select id = 'a'>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>

<select id = 'b'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>



    $('#a').on('change',function()
    {
        var type;
        type = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('#showsize').html(type);
    }
```

I did pass the selected item from . How can you show select both items from id=a,b and appear on HTML screen?

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(document).on('change','#a',function()
    {
        var value= $('#a option:selected').text();
        var value2=$('#b option:selected').text();

        $('#showsize').html("A Option:"+value+", B Option:"+value2);
    });
```

and if u want to show on change of b also

put `$(document).on('change','#a, #b',function()`

this ll show when any one of the selects are changed